# No overload for method 'GetDeviceSelector' takes 2 arguments

Tags: c#, overloading, outofrangeexception

I'm a complete beginner at c# and keep getting this error "CS1501   No overload for method 'GetDeviceSelector' takes 2 arguments"

Visual studio suggest to change `SerialDevice.GetDeviceSelector(vid, pid)` to `SerialDevice.GetDeviceSelectorFromUsbVidPid(vid, pid)`.

This works but when I run the debug on my Raspberry pi 3 on Windows 10 IoT Core it returns: 
`Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' in mscorlib.ni.dll
Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: index`

My goal is to connect my Arduino to my Raspberry pi and communicate with it through serial. (I don't want to use the Microsoft maker stuff)

Here's the full code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Http;
using Windows.ApplicationModel.Background;
using Windows.Devices.SerialCommunication;
using Windows.Devices.Enumeration;
using System.Diagnostics;

// The Background Application template is documented at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=533884&clcid=0x409

namespace BackgroundApplication1
{
    public sealed class StartupTask : IBackgroundTask
    {
        //private String debugtest;
        private SerialDevice serialDevice = null;



    public void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
    {
        // 
        // TODO: Insert code to perform background work
        //
        // If you start any asynchronous methods here, prevent the task
        // from closing prematurely by using BackgroundTaskDeferral as
        // described in http://aka.ms/backgroundtaskdeferral
        //
        FindDevice();
        Debug.WriteLine("test1");
    }

    /*private async void ListAvailablePorts()
    {
        UInt32 vid = 0x045E;
        UInt32 pid = 0x0611;
        try
        {
            string aqs = SerialDevice.GetDeviceSelector(vid, pid);
            var dis = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(aqs);

            //status.Text = "Select a device and connect";

            for (int i = 0; i < dis.Count; i++)
            {
                listOfDevices.Add(dis[i]);
            }

            DeviceListSource.Source = listOfDevices;
            comPortInput.IsEnabled = true;
            ConnectDevices.SelectedIndex = -1;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            status.Text = ex.Message;
        }
    }*/

    private async void FindDevice()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("begintest");
        ushort vid = 2341;
        ushort pid = 0001;

        string aqs = SerialDevice.GetDeviceSelectorFromUsbVidPid(vid, pid);

        var myDevices = await Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(aqs);

        try
        {
            serialDevice = await SerialDevice.FromIdAsync(myDevices[0].Id);

            Debug.WriteLine("ok");

            /*serialDevice.WriteTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000);
            serialDevice.ReadTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000);
            serialDevice.BaudRate = 9600;
            serialDevice.Parity = SerialParity.None;
            serialDevice.StopBits = SerialStopBitCount.One;
            serialDevice.DataBits = 8;
            serialDevice.Handshake = SerialHandshake.None;

            String debugtest = "Serial port configured successfully: ";
            debugtest += serialDevice.BaudRate + "-";
            debugtest += serialDevice.DataBits + "-";
            debugtest += serialDevice.Parity.ToString() + "-";
            debugtest += serialDevice.StopBits;
            //debugtest += (DeviceInformation)myDevices[0];

            Debug.WriteLine(debugtest);*/
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(exception.Message.ToString());
            Debug.WriteLine("error");
        }
        finally        
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Opened device for communication.");             
            Debug.WriteLine("test");
        }
        Debug.WriteLine("test2");
    }

    /*private void ShowStatus(string v)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }*/
  }
}
```

**edit: I changed some lines so that it works**

```
UInt16 vid = 0x2341;
        UInt16 pid = 0x0001;

        string aqs = SerialDevice.GetDeviceSelectorFromUsbVidPid(vid, pid);

        var myDevices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(aqs);

        if (myDevices.Count == 0)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Device not found!");
            return;
        }
```

But I found a new problem...
This `serialDevice = await SerialDevice.FromIdAsync(myDevices[0].Id);`
returns null

The capabilities are correct (when I compare it to Microsoft's sample)

```
<Capabilities>
<Capability Name="internetClient" />
<DeviceCapability Name="serialcommunication">
  <Device Id="any">
    <Function Type="name:serialPort"/>
  </Device>
</DeviceCapability>
```

Comment: are you getting exception at line `serialDevice = await SerialDevice.FromIdAsync(myDevices[0].Id);` ? Looks like you are getting an empty array of devices.

Comment: Yeah I just found that out...
I had to change UInt32 to UInt16 although it is UInt32 in Microsoft's sample...
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.serialcommunication.serialdevice#Windows_Devices_SerialCommunication_SerialDevice_FromIdAsync_System_String_

Comment: The problem is fixed but I found a new problem... This line: 
serialDevice = await SerialDevice.FromIdAsync(myDevices[0].Id);

Returns always null I checked the Package.appxmanifest multiple times and it is the same as the serialUART sample which works...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the ushort to UInt16 which solved the System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException error.

The solution for that

```
serialDevice = await SerialDevice.FromIdAsync(myDevices[0].Id);
```

returned null

is changing the variable *serialDevice* to *serialPort* for some annoying reason...

**Edit:** It worked once, it's broken again.... any ideas?

**Edit 2:** Someone gave me the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42793572/serialdevice-fromidasync-returns-null)