# SerialDevice.FromIdAsync() returns null

Tags: c#, serial-port, uwp, raspberry-pi3, windows-iot-core-10

I encountered a really strange problem when trying to connect my raspberry pi to my Arduino Uno through serial (usb).

```
serialPort = await SerialDevice.FromIdAsync(myDevices[0].Id);
```

Always returns null.
I tried many things and it won't until I put it in a loop and then it works the second time. So I removed the loop and made it run 2 times.

This is my output

```
begintest
testrange
\\?\USB#VID_2341&PID_0001#55639313633351210252#{86e0d1e0-8089-11d0-9ce4-08003e301f73}
test1
null
begintest
ok
ok2
debugtest2
gelukt
Opened device for communication.
test
test2
```

And here is my code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Http;
using Windows.ApplicationModel.Background;
using Windows.Devices.Enumeration;
using Windows.Devices.SerialCommunication;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace BackgroundApplication2
{
    public sealed class StartupTask : IBackgroundTask
    {
        private SerialDevice serialPort = null;
        public void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
        {
            FindDevice();
            Debug.WriteLine("test1");

            if (serialPort == null)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("null");
            }
            FindDevice();
        }


        private async void FindDevice()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("begintest");
            UInt16 vid = 0x2341;
            UInt16 pid = 0x0001;

            string aqs = SerialDevice.GetDeviceSelectorFromUsbVidPid(vid, pid);

            var myDevices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(aqs);

            if (myDevices.Count == 0)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Device not found!");
                return;
            }

            try
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("testrange");
                Debug.WriteLine(myDevices[0].Id);
                serialPort = await SerialDevice.FromIdAsync(myDevices[0].Id);
                if (serialPort == null)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("null2");
                    return;
                }
                Debug.WriteLine("ok");
                serialPort.WriteTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000);
                serialPort.ReadTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000);
                serialPort.BaudRate = 9600;
                serialPort.Parity = SerialParity.None;
                serialPort.StopBits = SerialStopBitCount.One;
                serialPort.DataBits = 8;
                serialPort.Handshake = SerialHandshake.None;
                Debug.WriteLine("ok2");
                /*String debugtest = "Serial port configured successfully: ";
                debugtest += serialPort.BaudRate + "-";
                debugtest += serialPort.DataBits + "-";
                debugtest += serialPort.Parity.ToString() + "-";
                debugtest += serialPort.StopBits;
                debugtest += (DeviceInformation)myDevices[0];

                Debug.WriteLine("debugtest1");
                Debug.WriteLine(debugtest);*/
                Debug.WriteLine("debugtest2");
                Listen();
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(exception.Message.ToString());
                Debug.WriteLine("error");
            }
            finally
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Opened device for communication.");
            }
            Debug.WriteLine("test2");
        }
        private async void Listen()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("gelukt");
        }
    }
}
```

For some reason this part makes it stuck. It just stops there...

```
String debugtest = "Serial port configured successfully: ";
debugtest += serialPort.BaudRate + "-";
debugtest += serialPort.DataBits + "-";
debugtest += serialPort.Parity.ToString() + "-";
debugtest += serialPort.StopBits;
debugtest += (DeviceInformation)myDevices[0];

Debug.WriteLine("debugtest1");
Debug.WriteLine(debugtest);
```

This is the output:

```
begintest
testrange
\\?\USB#VID_2341&PID_0001#55639313633351210252#{86e0d1e0-8089-11d0-9ce4-08003e301f73}
test1
null
begintest
ok
ok2
The thread 0x508 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[2308] serialsample.exe' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).
```

And my final question why does it automatically stop running? My debugging always exit's with this (or code -1 as seen above):

```
The program '[240] backgroundTaskHost.exe' has exited with code 1 (0x1).
```

Sorry if there's a dutch word here and there in my code.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain This is the first time I'm coding something like this so most of it is copy past. I don't really know why it's wrong but I'll google it, thanks! :)

Comment: turned my comment in to a full answer, showing what you where doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `IBackgroundTask` incorrectly, you must register your deferal and notifiy when it is complete. This is done by changing your `async void` functions to `async task` and making `Run` a `async void`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Http;
using Windows.ApplicationModel.Background;
using Windows.Devices.Enumeration;
using Windows.Devices.SerialCommunication;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BackgroundApplication2
{
    public sealed class StartupTask : IBackgroundTask
    {
        private SerialDevice serialPort = null;
        public void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
        {
            //This tells IBackgroundTask you will be doing some extra work in the background and it should not shut down.
            var deferral = taskInstance.GetDeferral();
            try
            {
                await FindDevice();
                Debug.WriteLine("test1");

                if (serialPort == null)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("null");
                }
                await FindDevice();
            }
            finally
            {
                //This tells IBackgroundTask that you are done with the last await.
                deferral.Complete();
            }
        }


        private async Task FindDevice()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("begintest");
            UInt16 vid = 0x2341;
            UInt16 pid = 0x0001;

            string aqs = SerialDevice.GetDeviceSelectorFromUsbVidPid(vid, pid);

            var myDevices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(aqs);

            if (myDevices.Count == 0)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Device not found!");
                return;
            }

            try
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("testrange");
                Debug.WriteLine(myDevices[0].Id);
                serialPort = await SerialDevice.FromIdAsync(myDevices[0].Id);
                if (serialPort == null)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("null2");
                    return;
                }
                Debug.WriteLine("ok");
                serialPort.WriteTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000);
                serialPort.ReadTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000);
                serialPort.BaudRate = 9600;
                serialPort.Parity = SerialParity.None;
                serialPort.StopBits = SerialStopBitCount.One;
                serialPort.DataBits = 8;
                serialPort.Handshake = SerialHandshake.None;
                Debug.WriteLine("ok2");
                /*String debugtest = "Serial port configured successfully: ";
                debugtest += serialPort.BaudRate + "-";
                debugtest += serialPort.DataBits + "-";
                debugtest += serialPort.Parity.ToString() + "-";
                debugtest += serialPort.StopBits;
                debugtest += (DeviceInformation)myDevices[0];

                Debug.WriteLine("debugtest1");
                Debug.WriteLine(debugtest);*/
                Debug.WriteLine("debugtest2");
                await Listen();
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(exception.Message.ToString());
                Debug.WriteLine("error");
            }
            finally
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Opened device for communication.");
            }
            Debug.WriteLine("test2");
        }
        private async Task Listen()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("gelukt");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I just read this: "There is one critical point to note: by default, the application will shut down when the run method completes." Thanks for your answer!

Comment: gelukt means 'suceeded' in Dutch